# Is there a simpler version of GridSearchCV that just optimizes a function?

Tags: python, optimization, scikit-learn

scikit-learn has a nice function `ParameterGrid` that creates a parameter grid from a dict of string to sequence:

[http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ParameterGrid.html]

This function is used by `GridSearchCV` that does exhaustive search over specified parameter values for an estimator. `GridSearchCV` allows for easy parallelization of the grid search. Here is a link:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV

I have a simpler problem: I just want to do exhaustive search for the minimum of a function over the parameter values. Given the output of `ParameterGrid` searching for the minimum is straightforward. But parallelization is a bit more complicated.

I wonder if there is a `GridSearch` function (without "CV" at the end), similar to `GridSearchCV`, that I could use for this simpler problem. If not, is there a way to "hack" `GridSearchCV`, passing it appropriate arguments so that it would do the job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GridSeachCV like "without crossvalidation" using this hack:
`cv` parameter of GridSearchCV should be `ShuffleSplit(1, test_size=0.01, n_iter=1, random_state=random_const)` and GridSearchCV should be like

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import ShuffleSplit

random_const = 123
grid_cv = GridSearchCV(estimator,
                       parameters_grid,
                       cv=ShuffleSplit(1, test_size=0.01, n_iter=1, random_state=random_const),
                       verbose=0,
                       n_jobs=1)
```